# Adding a dependency to make file c++

Tags: mysql, makefile

I'm trying to connect my app to a MySQL database on Linux. 
I compile my app using this command:

```
g++ -o mysqlconnect $(mysql_config --cflags) db.cpp $(mysql_config --libs)
```

and it works fine. But I can't seem to find a way to add `$(mysql_config --cflags)` and  `$(mysql_config --libs)` to my make file. Is there any way?

Comment: May I have a bit of feedback on my answer? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @YSC  My Makefile is composed of 1150 lines because i'm using an external library so i really couldn't figure out where to add the command that you provided. I gave your answer a vote up.

Answer (score 2):

If we are talking GNU Makefiles, the synthax is

```
g++ -o mysqlconnect $(shell mysql_config --cflags) db.cpp $(shell mysql_config --libs)
```

See the [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html).